# A quicker way to aggregate after get_dummies

Tags: pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have the following sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

array = {'id': [1,1,1,2,2,2], 'color': ['orange', 'pink', 'blue', 'green', 'pink', 'orange']}
df = pd.DataFrame(array)
pd.get_dummies(df)


    id  blue green orange pink
0   1   0   0   1   0
1   1   0   0   0   1
2   1   1   0   0   0
3   2   0   1   0   0
4   2   0   0   0   1
5   2   0   0   1   0
```

Looking for a way to aggregate the dummies. Expected output:

```
    id  blue green orange pink
0   1   1   0   1   1
1   2   0   1   1   1
```

Problem is that the original dataframe has more than 2 mil rows. Using groupby:

```
df.groupby('id').max()
```

takes a few hours long.

Any ideas to make it quicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change strategy and avoid the `get_dummies`:

Option1:

```
(df.groupby('id')['color']
   .apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
   .unstack(level=1)
   .fillna(0)
   .astype(int)
   .add_prefix('color_')
)
```

Option2:

```
(~df.groupby('id')['color']
    .apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
    .unstack(level=1)
    .isna()
).astype(int).add_prefix('color_')
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. However, the large dataframe gave an "unstacked dataframe is too big, causing int32 overflow" error for both options. Any ideas for a solution?

Comment: Can you give us more details on the real case dataset? How many rows/columns, IDs, min/max ID group size, etc. Optimization without the real dataset is difficult...

Answer (score 1):

From the 1st step change to `crosstab`

```
out = pd.crosstab(df.id,df.color).ne(0).astype(int)
Out[161]: 
color  blue  green  orange  pink
id                              
1         1      0       1     1
2         0      1       1     1
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. However, the large dataframe gave an "unstacked dataframe is too big, causing int32 overflow" error. Any ideas for a solution?